# Pandas Merge_Order with interpolate data logic

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series

I have two pandas dataframe. I would like to merge the two pandaframes, df1 and df2 into one, and I have used the following line

```
df1 = pd.merge_ordered(df1, df2, on='Time_Stamp')
```

But on top of that, I would like to fill in VWAP such that if it was missing, fill in the values using (bid + ask)/2.

Is there a way to do that?

Kind regards

df1 =

```
Time_Stamp bid ask
07:00:10   100 105
07:00:20   102 107
07:00:30   101 106
07:00:40   106 111
```

df2 =

```
Time_Stamp VWAP
07:00:10   103
07:00:20   ---
07:00:30   104
07:00:40   ---
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate VWAP for all of them if the equation stands for all rows

```
df1 = pd.merge_ordered(df1, df2, on='Time_Stamp')
df1['VWAP'] = (df1['bid'] + df1['ask']) / 2
```

This will repopulate the `VWAP` column with the result, or if you want to replace only those which are missing then

```
df1.loc[df1['VWAP'].isnull(), 'VWAP'] = (df1['bid'] + df1['ask']) / 2
```

Comment: I do not think answers the question. It would replace everything with the average not just the NaNs.

Comment: Sort of. It is answering the question if value of `VWAP` is derived same way

Comment: unfortunately, VWAP is not really the mid of bid+ask. I am just estimating VWAP from mid of bid+ask, where VWAP is missing

Comment: you can try the one which checks for the missing values, if it is missing then it calculates, otherwise the value stays.

Answer (score 0):

Once you merge the dataframes to variable `df12`, you can do:

```
df12.loc[df12.VWAP.isnull(), 'VWAP'] = (df12.bid + df12.ask) / 2
```

Output:

```
    Time_Stamp  bid ask VWAP
0   07:00:10    100 105 103.0
1   07:00:20    102 107 104.5
2   07:00:30    101 106 104.0
3   07:00:40    106 111 108.5
```

Comment: unfortunately, I get an error message so it didn't work